# Rails 4 has_many through many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I'm stuck on this:

```
class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills
  has_many :jobs, through: :skills
..
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :worker
  has_many :jobs
..
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills
  has_many :workers, through: :skills
..
end
```

What I'm trying to do is set up a many to many between `Skill` and `Job` inside of the `has_many' through relationship?

My question has three parts

1. Is this possible - using the has_many jobs rather than belongs_to jobs.
2. If it can be done and the code is wrong, how do I fix it?
3. How can I create Worker, Skill and Job records? (looking for syntax)

This is a picture (of sorts) of what I'm trying to do, hope it helps... :(

[image]

Comment: A suggestion.If you want to set `many to many` between `Skill` and `Job`,then either do with `has_and_belongs_to_many` or a normal `has_many :through`,but don't mess up with the both.

Comment: So I already have a has_many through that uses Skill.  Typically that would be set as belongs_to jobs, not has_many jobs.  So my question is whether the use of has_many jobs is valid within the context of the has_many through?  If so, it seems you're recommending creating another has_many through using Skill, Job and another, yet to be defined class?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: A normal join model has two `belongs_to` relationships that relates A to B in a many-to-many structure. I don't see one of those here. I'm not totally following what your relationships should be. Normally `belongs_to` pairs with `has_many`, but you apparently have two `has_many` relationships between Skill and Job.

Comment: tadman, that is my question exactly.  Can I actually use has_many though with a many to many relationship between Skill and Job?  If so, how might this be done?

Comment: Im not sure if it makes sense but you could add a `belongs_to :jobs` to your `Skill` model and then a `belongs_to :skills` in your `Jobs` model. Seems like it is a little hacky though

Comment: CWitty,  that's exactly what I did!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not giving active record enough information about your relationships. Every `:has_many` should have a corresponding `:belongs_to` so that active record knows which table holds the foreign key for each association. Notice that you only have one `:belongs_to` for three relationships. That smells.

As for fixing the problem, you have at least 2 options:

- add `:has_and_belongs_to_many` associations
- use explicit join tables

My preference is for the latter option. Being forced to name join tables often clarifies the nature of a relationship. On the flip side, I've found that `:has_and_belongs_to_many` is often too implicit and ends up making my designs more obscure.

**Explicit join tables**

You might setup your relationships like this (untested):

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :worker
  belongs_to :job
end

class Qualification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :worker
  belongs_to :skill
end

class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :qualifications
  has_many :skills, through: :qualifications

  has_many :assignments
  has_many :jobs, through: :assignments
  ..
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :qualifications
  has_many :workers, through: :qualifications
  has_many :jobs
  ..
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills
  has_many :workers, through: :assignments
  ..
end
```

By making the relationships more explicit I think the model is clearer. It should be easier to troubleshoot from here.

**EDIT:**

If you need to do a traversal like `Job.find(1).qualified_workers` try making the following adjustment to the above model:

```
class Job
  has_many :required_competencies
  has_many :skills, through: :required_competencies
  has_many :qualifications, through: :skills
  has_many :qualified_workers, through: qualifications, class_name: :workers
end

class RequiredCompetency
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

This is explicit about each traversal and names it. If you find these paths through your system are getting really long, I'd consider that a smell. There might be a more direct way to fetch your data or perhaps a better way to model it.

Comment: Thank you!  I am considering not using the assignments and finding jobs for workers through a call to skills....thoughts?

Comment: Can you explain the has_many :qualified_workers?  I would like to traverse from workers to Jobs and visa versa, so this is feeling right.  I would say that this is an example that masks my actual class names, so for the example please also consider that Worker to Skill is a 1:many not many:many.  Thanks!!! :-\

Comment: Qualified_workers allows you to go from Jobs to Workers. I could have changed the name to just `workers` but I think that makes your model less obvious. You can't directly go from Jobs to Workers, your requirements dictate intermediate criteria. Prefixing the method with something descriptive makes that more obvious.

Comment: To do the reverse query you'd setup something similar on `Workers`. Personally I try to avoid these long chains. It usually means that my object model could be improved...

Comment: I was kind of feeling that might be the case, and have reduced the model.  You input was thoughtful and spot on.  Thanks!!